# How to Pass commands to custom linux Service using bash / terminal

Tags: linux, bash, service, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Goal: Run a custom bash script as a service in linux and allow me to pass commands to it like you can to most other services via terminal/bash.

I already have a script set up and tested that can do what I need it to, except I can't figure out how to be able to pass commands to it like you would other services.
Example: nano  opens up the nano editor to read specified file. 
I want to perform 'fan on', which will call the new service 'fan' and execute the 'on' command.
Bonus: Being able to save the variables into a config file to be modified later on. But for now, I have the variables set at top of script so its not totally necessary.

Current Unit File:

```
[Unit]
Description=Fan control Service                                                                                                                                                                         
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
ExecStart=/home/pi/Documents/FanControl.sh
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash


#########################################################
#  User Settings
#GPIO Pin Number to use to control fan transistor.
fanpin=3
#Celsius temp to turn fan on/off
offtemp=55
ontemp=60
#Turn on the looping script automatically or not
autostart=TRUE
#Determine how often to scan temp and turn fan on/off if in auto
sleepinterval=10

#########################################################

#Misc Variables used in script - Leave these alone - Base Settings
MaxTemp=0
FanState=OFF
mode=MANUAL
auto=FALSE

#########################################################
#          Functions Described Below 
#########################################################

before-start() {
    # Check if gpio is already exported
    if [ ! -d /sys/class/gpio/gpio$fanpin ]
    then
      #Export the Pin
      echo $fanpin > /sys/class/gpio/export
      sleep 1 ;# Short delay while GPIO permissions are set up
      echo Fan Pin Exported Successfully.
      # Setup the pin as an output  
      sudo echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$fanpin/direction
    fi
    }

#Function to turn fan on
on() {
        # Sets FanPin to high
        echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$fanpin/value
        FanState=ON
        mode=Manual
        auto=FALSE
        echo Fan Turned on -- Mode set to Manual.
        echo
    }

#Function to turn fan off
off() {
        # Sets FanPin to low
        echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio$fanpin/value
        FanState=OFF
        mode=Manual
        auto=FALSE
        echo Fan Turned off -- Mode set to Manual.
        echo
    }   

#Function to set the variables to values
#Haven't actually tested this function yet
Set() {
    if $2 = "ontemp"
    then
        ontemp=$2
    else
        $2=$3
    fi
}

#########################################################
#    Begin Service Execution Code
#########################################################
#Don't know whow to write this section to keep it running as a service
#But it works well for testing purposes
before-start
    on
    sleep 3
    off
echo
read -p "Select an action": Q
$Q
echo
action="$1"
serviceName="Fan-Control Service"
echo Exiting Fan Service
```

I can use systemctl daemon-reload and it can load the service.
I can use 'systemctl start fan' and the service starts successfully without error. it will also run the fan for a few seconds, so i know its starting fine.

When attempting to use 'fan on' as a bash command, i get "command not found"
- how can i get this as a working command?
- what changes do I need in the script to keep it alive to be able to pass such commands to it later on?

Comment: I don't quite follow.  You have a script that can turn the fan on or off, and you want to use it to manually control the fan on demand.  All good so far.  But why does it need to be a system service?  It seems like what you're looking for is an ordinary command.

Comment: it doesn't *need* to be a service, but this is more a proof-of-concept for me while I experiment with other items I want to try to do. Plus, I want it to start automatically when the system starts, which I know I can do via a cron-job on the script. This is a proof-of-concept while i learn the in-and-outs. I have found very little/inconsistent/incomplete information on how to set up unit files and services in linux.

My end-goal is having a service that acts as a vpn-kill switch that looks at the 'nordvpn status' command and kills certain apps if disconnected, and restarts once connected.

Comment: @JohnBollinger by the way, thanks for that tip. After a google search, i found out where to put that script and have it as a custom command like I want. So that solves on aspect of my question, but I am still curious as to how to get a custom service running. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ok, so is the question now about how generally to implement your own system service, or is it still about services that support interactive commands?

Comment: a service that supports interactive commands would be ideal. That way i could execute 'fan status' and have it readout the the current status. running this as a one-off command will re-initialize the variables at the top, then report those variables, instead of the last ones set. Though, i suppose reading/writing the states to a config file could get around that, instead of having it sit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

It is atypical for services to respond to interactive commands other than service-management commands drawn from a pre-defined set.  If that's the concept you are trying to prove then I would suggest choosing a different direction.

But if you must do it, then you have viable alternatives:

- for an on / off toggle, consider setting up a signal handler in the service script, say for `SIGUSR1`.  You can send signals directly via the `kill` command, but I would recommend instead providing a separate script for the purpose.
- for more complex instructions or more than a very small number of distinct instructions, you need some kind of communication channel.  The script could potentially use a FIFO or a socket for this purpose, and in that case I would again recommend a separate script for sending commands.  But this will require your service to be *substantially* more complex.

In any case, do note that although there's a long tradition of service-*control* scripts, service implementations themselves are rarely scripts.  They are normally compiled programs, typically written in C, as this provides more direct access to the system and finer control, and is also considered by many to be more secure (when done competently).

Comment: Thanks for the information. After some additional research promoted by this reply and the other user conversation, I think I can do what I want with a simple script placed in /use/bin.   I’ve modified my code to look at a config file and will be looking to fork out the loop if that gets called. That way the script can modify the config file, and the loop will look at the config to see if I asked for it to stop or adjust operation.   I’ll add a cron job to start the loop when system starts and it should be all good after that. Thanks

Comment: My idea originated after setting up deluge, which has a how-to make it a service ad was hoping to have that service quit if nordvpn disconnects. But a script running in background should suffice. I was just having trouble killing / starting deluge from a script. But after this experiment I think I I understand much more about scripting and might be able to accomplish it.